# Continuous processing mode and python udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

does Spark 2.4.0 support Python UDFs with Continuous Processing mode?

In my simple code i'm consuming from a kafka topic, doing some trivial processing per-row (basically add a dummy field to the json messages) and write out to another topic.

However i dont see any messages in the output topic when i trigger using continuous mode. If i dont use the python udf, then it works fine.

EDIT: This [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27234) (unrelated to this post) reported lack of support.

Comment: I'll post sample code on Monday

Comment: An issue has been filed about this. 

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27234

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried myself, I believe not. The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#supported-queries) lists the supported operations; udfs are not on the list.